# Translate camera in front of the image using Threejs

Tags: javascript, image, camera, three.js, scene

Hi I am trying to make a UI with THREE.js:

https://jsfiddle.net/jperezmedina/g7c2hn1v/20/

On the UI I put five images. The first image is placed on the position `(x: 300, y: -150, z: 100)`. I need centered the images in fonction of the screen size of the browser. Below you will find a picture of my situation.

The JSFiddle runs but it doesn't seem translate the image in function of the position of the first image. Thanks for the ideas !

[image]

**EDIT:** The solution I want to have is to see the center of the image in the center of the screen while keeping the image in the coordinate (x: 300, y: -150, z: 100). A second image describe it.

[image]

Comment: you want to position the image in the middle of screen ?or do you want to rotate images parallel to blue plain?

Comment: @FastSnail I edited my post to give you more details. Thanks !

Comment: if you want to position images in middle why do you give x:300 y:...?if you add meshes to 0 cordinate it's the middle.not sure is it what you want or not .see https://jsfiddle.net/g7c2hn1v/22/

Comment: Unfortunately, my images must be placed in another position that (x=0, y=0). For this example i used (x:300, y:...) I want add meshes to  cordinates != to 0.